# java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion failed - Android JUnit Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

```
 @Before
fun setUp() {
    val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    testScheduler = TestScheduler()
    val testSchedulerProvider = TestSchedulerProvider(testScheduler)
    sharedViewModel = SharedViewModel(
        testSchedulerProvider,
        compositeDisposable,
        networkHelper,
        repository, notesRepository, userPreferences
    )
    sharedViewModel.noteSaving.observeForever(
        noteSavingObserver
    )
    sharedViewModel.clearNoteText.observeForever(clearNoteTextObserver)

}


@Test
fun givenServerResponse200_whenNotesSaved_shouldclearTextField() {
    val notes = "testNote"
    val latitude = 3.62176
    val longitude = -7.932457
    sharedViewModel.notesField.value = notes
    sharedViewModel.latLongField.value =
        LocationModel(latitude, longitude)
    sharedViewModel.currentLocation.value = "test location"
    val newNote = Notes(latitude, longitude, notes, userPreferences.getUserId())
    doReturn(true)
        .`when`(networkHelper)
        .isNetworkConnected()

    doReturn(Single.just(true))
        .`when`(notesRepository).addNotes(newNote)
    assert(sharedViewModel.clearNoteText.value == Event("Note Saved Successfully"))

    sharedViewModel.addNote()
    testScheduler.triggerActions()
}
```

I am not able to assert a statement which is getting failed for some reason though I have mocked the requirements. I couldn't identify the reason

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your SharedViewModel class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you'd compare a `String` to some `Event`, which equals apples & pears.

It might rather be something alike:

```
sharedViewModel.clearNoteText.value.equals("Note Saved Successfully")
```

or:

```
sharedViewModel.clearNoteText.value == "Note Saved Successfully"
```